# How to decrease the space between two input fields

Tags: html, css

I need to decrease the space between two input fields, below are my properties, I tried changing the margin but didnt work. please suggest

```
.SecValue {
  display: inline-block;
  float: right;
  height: 20px;
  max-width: 90px;
  min-width: 70px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

<tr class="selectheight5">
  <td class="tdLabelWidth">
    <form:label class="sectionLabel" path="">Code</form:label>
  </td>
  <td class="tdInputWidth">
    <form:select id="formState">
      <form:option value="0">Select</form:option>
      <form:option value="RE">RE</form:option>
    </form:select>
    <form:input class="SecValue" id="formcode" type="search" maxlength="5" />
    <form:label id="errorformState" class="sectionError" path=""></form:label>
    <form:label id="errorformcode" class="sectionError" path=""></form:label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

[image: embedded image]

Comment: Post your HTML too please. We need a [mcve]

Comment: Please post the code and classes for both the text-boxes.

Comment: Please post full code.

Comment: Vertical or horizontal space?

Comment: updated  html code

Comment: The problem looks like your input field is set to float: right, so the label/select will be left aligned and the input will be as far right as possible. You either need to force the container to be less wide, or remove the float and use margin-left instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can just remove the `float: right`

```css
.SecValue {
  display: inline-block;
  /*float: right;*/
  height: 20px;
  max-width: 90px;
  min-width: 70px;
  text-align: left;
  color: #666666;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Sans-serif;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<tr class="selectheight5">
  <td class="tdLabelWidth">
    <label class="sectionLabel" path="">Code</label>
  </td>
  <td class="tdInputWidth">
    <select id="formState">
      <option value="0">Select</option>
      <option value="RE">RE</option>
    </select>
    <input class="SecValue" id="formcode" type="search" maxlength="5" />
    <label id="errorformState" class="sectionError" path=""></label>
    <label id="errorformcode" class="sectionError" path=""></label>
  </td>
</tr>
```